# Attempting to create a basic socket connection in C and running into an infinite loop on accept()

Tags: c, sockets, http

I have an assignment where I need to create a simple HTTP server to handle GET requests and return info from a directory in the directory holding the executable for this code. I am trying to establish a connection between the sockets before ironing out the HTTP requests. However, when I try to connect the client to the server using `accept()` it triggers an infinite loop with gdb displaying this message:

```
../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/accept.c:26
26      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/accept.c: No such file or directory.
```

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc>1){
        perror("Error there should be no command line arguments");
        exit(0);
    }
    int sockfd = 0;
    int clientfd = 0;
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))<0){ //create socket and check for error
        perror("Error in socket creation");
        exit(0);
    }
//create sockaddr object to hold info about the socket
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = 0;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    socklen_t sockSize = sizeof(server);
//Bind the socket to a physical address exit if there is an error
    if((bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sockSize))<0){
        perror("Error binding socket");
        exit(0);
    }
//Check server details
    printf("-------Server Details----------\n");
    printf("Port number %d | IP ADDRESS %d\n", ntohs(server.sin_port), (getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, &sockSize)));
    if((getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, &sockSize)) <0){
        perror("There is an error in the sock");
        exit(0);
    }
    if(listen(sockfd, 5) <0){
        perror("Error switching socket to listen");
        exit(0);
    }
    while((clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client, (socklen_t*)&sockSize))){
        printf("Socket is awaiting connections");
    }
// figure out how to setup client to accept and submit HTTP requests
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what infinite loop? You **have** a loop there, and you forgot to add  `\n` at the end of your message so you won't see anything

Comment: even when I add the \n and and exit(0) after the print in the while loop the executable still infinite loops, even when accept is written standalone.

Comment: `while((clientfd = accept(...))` that will evaluate to "true" and enter the loop even when `accept()` failed and returned -1. Notice that 0 is valid fd value that can be returned by `accept()`. Include `err.h` and hange your `printf(...)` to a `warn` to see why it's failing.

Comment: Looking harder, it seems that your program have its logic backwards. It should be `for(;;){ if((client_fd = accept(...)) == -1) fail_or_break; ... otherwise (fork and) handle HTTP request on client_fd ...; close(client_fd); }` (or without the `for(;;)` if you want to handle a single client).

Answer (score 1):

`accept()` returns -1 on failure.  An `if` will treat *any* non-zero value as a `true` condition.

Your loop should look more like the following:

```c
// setup listening socket...

printf("Socket is awaiting connections");

while (1) {
    sockSize = sizeof(client); // <-- add this

    if ((clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client, (socklen_t*)&sockSize)) < 0) {
        if (errno != EINTR) {
            // fatal error, bail out...
            break;
        }
        continue; // retry...
    }

    printf("Client connected");

    // use clientfd to read HTTP request and send HTTP response...

    close(clientfd);
}
```